# Replacement graphics card for a R9 290X CF setup

Tags: graphics-cards, high-end

I'm looking for a proper replacement card (or cards) for my current R9 290X cards. I currently run two of them in CF (three will not increase the performance significant, only the power consumption).

Current specs (with the R9 cards):

- CPU: i7-8086K @ 5.00GHz (Delid)
- RAM: Corsair RGB 16GB DDR4
- ASUS ROG Z370X Board
- BeQuiet 1kW PSU
- Samsung SSD 850

The card(s) should perform well (60 FPS+) with a 5760x1200 resolution, and should be able to handle games like "Shadow of the Tomb Raider" maxed out.

Can anyone recommend a card, or a CF/SLI setup?

Comment: Budget? Otherwise I'd say just pick from the current line of top end cards.

Comment: Basically I've got no budget cap, as long as it's useful, and I'm not sure if for example the RTX 2080 Ti 11GB can fulfill my expectations...

Comment: If that card can't fulfill your expectations, you might want to reevaluate those expectations. Is gaming your primary concern?

Comment: Yeah, and that's why I'm here, maybe anyone is driving also such a high res and can recommend something. The card will be maxed out at gaming, yes.

Comment: Well, you can't go any higher than a 2080 Ti right now, so I'd say go for it if you got that kind of cash to spend. I don't otherwise have the right answer regarding resolutions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5760x1200 is 6,912,000 pixels, which is 1 billion less pixels than true 4k resolution (3840×2160, 8,294,400 pixels), so 4k framerates could be comparable to 5760x1200 framerates (but take it with a grain of salt, as for ultrawide resolutions like 5760x1200 the GPU would need more memory to load textures).

So it might be worth to get two GTX 1080 Ti and use them in SLI - according to benchmark they will outperform 2080 Ti for almost the same cost:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiK0bomLrvM

That is unless you want to throw money and get two 2080 Ti in SLI - nothing would beat it, but you would spend $1000 more for a marginal increase in performance (and a chance of getting a faulty GPU, since Nvidia's 20xx series were having a lot of troubles and bad chips).

You should also consider upgrading your RAM and SSD to max out your rig performance, to something like this Intel Optane in RAID 0 https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820167440 for storage and at least 32 GB of RAM either at 4133MHz and 17 CAS latency like this G.SKILL F4-4133C17Q-32GTZR https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820232677 or this 4700MHz Corsair CMW16GX4M2K4700C19 https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820236447 and also investing in custom professional liquid cooling for your rig, as this will allow you to OC your GPU's and CPU even more.

Comment: Ty for the long answer. I decided to go for a single RTX, and buy another one when they got a bit cheaper (Since the upgradability is limited, when i go for the dual GTX's). The RAM's are already maxed out - and i got a RAID0 running; A custom water cooling loop is installed already too. :)

Comment: @Essigwurst Be aware that RTX has a bad reputation for a huge number of defective chips: https://www.kitguru.net/components/graphic-cards/damien-cox/nvidia-rtx-is-seeing-an-unusually-high-number-of-failure-reports/

Comment: I noticed that, so I gone for the ASUS 11GB Dual version, it seems to be "clean".